# Mockito: how verify static method called in non-static method?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, static-methods

I have `Animal.class`:

```
class Animal {
    int counter;
    public void move() {
        counter += getRandomNumber(1, 10);
    }

    public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return new Random().nextInt(min, max);
    }
}
```

I use `Mockito 5.2.0`.

Tried verify `getRandomNumber` method with `mockedStatic` interface:

```
@Test
void tryVerifyStaticMethod() {
    try (MockedStatic<Animal> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Animal.class)) {
        mockedStatic.verify(() -> Animal.getRandomNumber(1, 10), times(1));
    }
}
```

But I don't know how call non-static `move()` method in the test for invoking `getRandomNumber` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call a method that is calling your static mocks, you can do it simply in the try-block. As long as your static mock is present, it will be used for the calls.

This means, your test could look like the following:

```
@Test
void tryVerifyStaticMethod() {

    try (MockedStatic<Animal> mockedStatic = mockStatic(Animal.class)) {

        // Giving your static mock some behaviour if you want
        mockedStatic.when(() -> Animal.getRandomNumber(1, 10)).thenReturn(42);

        // creating a new instance of animal
        Animal animal = new Animal();

        // calling the method under test
        animal.move();

        // asserting that the counter has changed
        assertEquals(42, animal.counter);

        // verifying the call of the random number method
        mockedStatic.verify(() -> Animal.getRandomNumber(1, 10), times(1));
    }

}
```

As long as you are calling `move()` inside the `try`, all the static calls to your `Animal` class will use the `mockedStatic` object and all of its behaviours. In this example case, I gave the behaviour to return `42` whenever `getRandomNumber` with `min` = 1 and `max` = 10 is called.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't test the internal details of your class, test its behaviour. In your case I would rewrite animal like this:

```
class Animal {
    int counter;
    int Random random;
    public Animal(Random random) {
     this.random = random;
    }

    public void move() {
        counter += getRandomNumber(1, 10);
    }

    // there must be some method which shows the effect of calling move()
    public int getCounter() {
         return counter;
    }

    private int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
        return random.nextInt(min, max);
    }
}
```

Then your test becomes:

```
@Test
public void testMove() {
    Random random = mock(Random.class);
    when(random.nextInt(1, 10)).thenReturn(5);
    Animal animal = new Animal(random);
    animal.move();
    assertEquals(5, animal.getCounter());
}
```

Avoid calling `new` in classes which you wish to test.
You can keep `getRandomeNumber` as `static`, if you wish, and pass it the `Random` instance as a parameter, but I don't see any good reason to do that.

Comment: But I cannot change the `Animal.class` structure unfortunalely. :(

Comment: If someone is asking you to write unit tests for code, they need to allow you to refactor it for testability.